# I cant find the elements using FindViewById

Tags: android

I have 2 LinearLayouts inside of each other one the horizontal one is inside the vertical one . Some of the elements are not detected that are inside the horizontal Liner Layout using FindViewById (EditText , and a button) . And Yes I tried to save ...Thanks In advance. What I am basically doing is trying to create a web browser.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/llb"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="10px"
android:minWidth="10px"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="URL"
        android:imeActionLabel="GO"
        android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="data" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="New Tab"
        android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_800" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="History"
        android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_800" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your view bind code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code , on onCreate() you need to do as follow :

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.llb); // root linear layout
View view1 = view.findViewById(R.id.ll1); //first child of root
```

then you can access your EditText :

```
EditText et = view1.findViewById(R.id.t1);
```

That's because you use nested layouts.

Also, please use **CTRL+ALT+L** for formatting your xml file for being more readable.